# Arch mingw: Using a python version installed with pacman

Tags: python, archlinux

I am currently using the [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) Building Platform which uses an arch shell to allow users to install their packages via the pacman package manager. On this shell, neither $PYTHONHOME nor $PYTHONPATH are set, and issuing `which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3`. I have used pacman to install a python version I would actually like to be using, which is located in `/mingw64/lib/python3.9/`. My first approach was to issue:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=/mingw64/lib/python3.9/
exec bash
```

But this did not change the output of `which python3` or `which python`. I have also tried modifying the `PYTHONPATH` variable in a virtual environment but this has not worked either. How can I made the adjustments necessary so that the aliases `python` and `python3` automatically point to the desired python installation?

Comment: Not a solution, bt MSYS2 `python3` is `python3.9`. So essentially you are referencing to the same program.

Comment: Bash or other shells don't care about `PYTHONPATH`, they look at `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to find the location of the `mingw64` python installation by issuing

```
pacman -Q1 | grep /mingw64/bin/
```

and then appending it to $PATH by issuing

```
export PATH=mingw-w64-x86_64-python:$PATH
```

and then reloading the python alias paths by issuing

```
exec bash
```